# How to remove package (sendmail) for which I aborted the installation?

Tags: apt, package-management, email, sendmail

I thought I wanted to install `sendmail`, so I did

```
sudo apt-get install sendmail
```

but during the (very long (5min+) and slow) installation process, I discovered I did not need this package after all. So I pressed `Ctrl+C` and aborted the installation. Then, I tried to remove it by

```
sudo apt-get purge sendmail
```

. This removed some stuff, but definitely not all of it, as there still is a `sendmail` binary in my system:

```
eelke@eelkebox:/etc/alternatives$ which sendmail
/usr/sbin/sendmail

eelke@eelkebox:/etc/alternatives$ ll /usr/sbin/ | grep sendmail
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root    root      23572 Feb 11  2014 checksendmail*
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root    root         12 Feb 11  2014 hoststat -> sendmail-mta*
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root    root         27 Feb 11  2014 mailstats -> ../share/sendmail/mailstats*
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root    root         12 Feb 11  2014 purgestat -> sendmail-mta*
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root    root         26 Oct  8 14:13 sendmail -> /etc/alternatives/sendmail*
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root    root      21677 Feb 11  2014 sendmailconfig*
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root    root         30 Oct  8 14:13 sendmail-msp -> /etc/alternatives/sendmail-msp*
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root    root         30 Oct  8 14:13 sendmail-mta -> /etc/alternatives/sendmail-mta*
```

Now I would really like to get rid of all sendmail-related stuff and get back to a clean system. Any ideas? This is on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Answer (score 0):

`aptitude` can help with removing packages that were only partially installed applications.

```
sudo apt-get install aptitude
sudo aptitude purge
```

All packages that are no longer depended upon will be removed.

Comment: Hmm I've wondered about that. These are the packages it then wants to remove:  linux-headers-3.16.0-45 linux-headers-3.16.0-45-generic linux-image-3.16.0-45-generic linux-image-extra-3.16.0-45-generic procmail  sensible-mda

So also all these headers etc. In the past I've had some trouble `autoremove`-ing one of those, so am a bit hesitant. Are you sure this will fix it?

Comment: @EelkeSpaak You can but try :D - it won't mess up your system, since your using `autoremove`

Comment: OK I've tried it, but sendmail is still there in /usr/sbin/sendmail and all the places that one symlinks to... Edit: I really think the problem is with me aborting the installation. So any general fix for cleaning up an aborted installation would be very helpful.

Comment: @EelkeSpaak the problem is that the `purge` command you entered is **meant** to remove binaries

Comment: @EelkeSpaak You can use `aptitude` - see edit

Comment: `aptitude purge` is not removing anything over and above what `apt-get purge` was also removing. The files are still there.

Comment: @EelkeSpaak Add the packagename on the end

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant, that does not do anything other than `apt-get purge`.